# DateTimeControl in MMMM/YYYY format

Tags: asp.net, aspx, datetimecontrol

How to make a SharePoint:DateTimeControl use a MMMM/YYYY format so it let the user choose only month and year ?

Answer (score 1):

I think is not possible. You need to use another control like [jQuery UI Datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) and use this format:

```
dateFormat: 'MM yy'
```

Comment: DateTimePicker and DateTimeControl aren't the same class. The later don't have Format and CustomFormat properties. Can I use DateTimePicker in a aspx page actually ?

Comment: My mistake. You are right. You're going to have to go for something like jquery.